How to use two different images for light and dark mode in android studio using XML only?
My light mode image appears but when I use another image for dark mode, my dark mode page turns black with everything in it. I'll share my xml here for better understanding:
bg_light_layer xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable= "#ffd3b4"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/bg_light"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:alpha=".6">
        </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>

theme xml: (light mode)
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="SCREEN">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_light_layer</item>
    </style>

</resources>


activity_main xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    style="@style/SCREEN"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

(https://i.sstatic.net/7OTmsfeK.jpg)
(https://i.sstatic.net/D5cdXe4E.png)
I used 'bg_light.png' for light mode and 'bg_dark.png' for dark mode with EXACT SAME CODE replacing 'bg_light.png' with 'bg_dark.png' in bg_dark_layer xml then theme xml (dark). BUT my entire dark mode turns into a black screen when I do this. NOTE: I kept the images in res/drawable, bg_light_layer.xml & 'bg_dark_layer.xml' in res/drawable and themes (light and dark) in res/values (as default). I also tried multiple images for dark theme but didn't work.

When implementing dark mode resources like icons or any other drawable, you don't need to change anything in your default themes.xml file. You only need to create Android Resource Directory for the night mode drawables.

Go your module's res folder. Right click > New > Android Resource Directory



On the window opened, you should select drawable as resource type and select Night Mode as a qualifier:


After adding drawable directory with Night Mode qualifier switch to Project mode in Android Studio and under your module's res folder now you should be able to see drawable-night directory:





Now that you just have to put your background images with the same name to these related folders respectively. (light one goes to normal drawable dir, and the dark one goes to drawable-night dir WITH THE SAME NAME)
After these configurations you can use your drawable that differs according to your app's theme with same name.
